# html tags in foundation framework for email's frontmatter

Tags: html, yaml-front-matter

Is it possible to add br tag in front-matter (using foundation for email)? Or line-break that's equivalent of `<br />`.

I am trying to add something like:

```
---
myTextHeadline: Text has a <br /> line break.
myText: Can text have an <em>emphasis</em> tag as well?
---
```

So far I have looked into the documentation and some frontmatter forums but haven't been able to find anything useful. Some of the solutions suggested in non-foundation forums gives me a panini error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was super easy. Answering so that others can benefit.

Change

```
---
myTextHeadline: Text has a <br /> line break.
myText: Can text have an <em>emphasis</em> tag as well?
---
```

to

```
---
myTextHeadline: "Text has a <br /> line break."
myText: "Can text have an <em>emphasis</em> tag as well?"
---
```

While calling, use `{{{myTextHeadline}}}` instead of `{{myTextHeadline}}`

Comment: I'm using jekyll. This is giving me an error when I switch from 2 {{ to 3 {{{: Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 22): Unexpected character { in "{{{ page.author_bio }}}" in /_layouts/community_post.html